# how to make a select to display the data from the customers table ordered by birth data? in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have records in the "birth-data" column. I'm trying to make a report that shows all the customers ordered by month and day of birth:

### |customer| birth-data|

|  john  |   01.05.1982|
|  mary  |   15.02.1986|
|  Clark |   19.04.1989|
|  Lee   |   22.11.1987|
|  Jonas |   03.03.1992|
|  Bia   |   03.02.1996|

thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the issue - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Use report Sorting & Grouping features. Is birth-data a date/time field? Advise not to use punctuation/special characters in object naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by just month and day and disregard year, calculate a field that extracts month and day and use that for sorting.

`MoDy: Format([birth-data], "mmdd")`

Or calculate fields for month and day and use those in sorting

`Mo: Month([birth-data])`
`Dy: Day([birth-data])`

Use report Sorting & Grouping feature.